# Passing parameters into methods

Tags: java, parameters, parameter-passing

I have been set a challenge to create a temperature program that will allow the user to input temperatures for each day of the week, then allow them to choose which day they wish to view the temperature for, display the average temperature for the week and then exit.

However I am having trouble with the parameters, when it comes to the switch, when I call average();  and  day();    it underlines red?
Also in my method 'average' Java says i need a return statement, but I didn't think I did?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * Date: 28/01/2015
 * Time: 15:53
 * UPDATE COMMENT ABOUT PROGRAM HERE
 */
public class Temp
{
   static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
   static int choice;
   static double average, finalAverage;




   public static void temp()
   {
      double monTemp,tuesTemp,wedTemp,thursTemp,friTemp,satTemp,sunTemp;

      System.out.println("You have chosen option 1");
      System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Monday in degrees celsius");
      monTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();


      System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Tuesday in degrees celsius");
      tuesTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();


      System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Wednesday in degrees celsius");
      wedTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Thursday in degrees celsius");
      thursTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Friday in degrees celsius");
      friTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Saturday in degrees celsius");
      satTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Sunday in degrees celsius");
      sunTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

   }//Temp

   public static void day(double monTemp, double tuesTemp, double wedTemp, double thursTemp, double friTemp, double satTemp, double sunTemp)
   {

      System.out.println("You have chosen to see the temperature for a specified day");
      System.out.println("Please choose a day below");
      System.out.println(" 1. Monday");
      System.out.println(" 2. Tuesday");
      System.out.println(" 3. Wednesday");
      System.out.println(" 4. Thursday");
      System.out.println(" 5. Friday");
      System.out.println(" 6. Saturday");
      System.out.println(" 7. Sunday ");
      choice = keyboard.nextInt();

      if (choice==1)

      {
         System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Monday");
         System.out.println(" The temperature for Monday is " +monTemp + "°C");
      }//if

      if  ( choice== 2)
      {
         System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Tuesday");
         System.out.println(" The temperature for Tuesday " + tuesTemp+ "°C");

      }//if
      else if ( choice== 3)
      {
         System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Wednesday");
         System.out.println(" The temperature for Wednesday is " +wedTemp + "°C");
      }//elseif
      else if ( choice== 4)
      {
         System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Thursday");
         System.out.println(" The temperature for Thursday is " +thursTemp + "°C");
      }//elseif
      else if ( choice== 5)
      {
         System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Friday");
         System.out.println(" The temperature for Friday is " +friTemp + "°C");
      }//elseif
      else if ( choice== 6)
      {
         System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Saturday");
         System.out.println(" The temperature for Saturday is " +satTemp + "°C");
      }//if
      else if (choice==7)
      {
         System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Sunday");
         System.out.println(" The temperature for Sunday is " +sunTemp + "°C");
      }//elseif
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Oops something went wrong, please try again");
         day(monTemp, tuesTemp, wedTemp, thursTemp, friTemp, satTemp, sunTemp);
      }//else



   }//day

   public static double average(double monTemp, double tuesTemp, double wedTemp, double thursTemp, double satTemp, double sunTemp, double friTemp)
   { //error here
      average=monTemp+tuesTemp+wedTemp+thursTemp+friTemp+satTemp+sunTemp;
      finalAverage=(average/7);

      System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the average temperature for the week");
      System.out.println(" The temperature for the week is " +finalAverage + "°C");

   }//Average

   public static void menu()
   {

      System.out.println("Welcome the temperature program. Please select an option for the menu below b entering the number");
      System.out.println("1)Enter temperatures for each day of the week");
      System.out.println("2)Display average temperature for specified choice");
      System.out.println("3)Display average temperature for the week");
      System.out.println("4)Exit");
      choice = keyboard.nextInt();

      switch (choice)
      {
         case 1:

            temp();
            menu();
            break;


         case 2:

            day();
            menu();
            break;

         case 3:

            average(); //error here
            menu();
            break;


         case 4:

            System.exit(0);



         default:
            System.out.println("Oops, something went wrong, please try again!");
            menu();
      }//switch
   }//menu

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      menu();

   }//main
}//class
```

Comment: "*I am having trouble with the parameters, when it comes to the switch.*" Please explain these troubles.

Comment: Ditto on explaining troubles. You could also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). `average` is declared as `public static double average` meaning that it is declared to return a `double`. There needs to be a return statement to satisfy that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `temp()` method stores the temperatures in *local variables*.

Local variables only exist in the block that defines them. That is, in the `temp` method. As soon as that method is finished, they are gone.

For this reason, you don`t have the data available to you when you need to run another method, like the`average()` method.

You should define your temperatures as fields. In fact, it would be best to use an array if you have learned how to use it. But whether you use an array or not, you have to declare them as fields - before all constructors and methods.

All your methods are static, and therefore you'll have to define them as static fields (although in general you should try to avoid programs that do everything statically) like your average and finalAverage.

When you define them as fields (remember not to re-define them in `temp()`! Only assign to them, do not declare them there), you'll be able to access them from the other methods. You then have two choices:

1. Don't declare them as parameters to `day()` and `average()`, but rather, use them directly. In this case `day()` and `average()` will be declared without parameters, and you don't have to change anything in the `switch` in `menu`.
2. Declare them as parameters, but remember to pass them as parameters from `menu`.

You have another serious problem, and that is that `menu()` calls itself recursively. In theory, if you use the program for a long time, you'll get a Stack Overflow exception. You shouldn't be calling `menu()` from itself. You should have a loop that displays the menu, and takes choices until the choice is to exit.

As for the return statement, the other answers already told you - if you declared a method with a return type, then you must return something. If you don't want to return anything from the method, it must be declared `void`.

Remember that methods should be used in a way that matches the way they were declared. If you call a method that has parameters, you have to pass it arguments. And if you declare a return type, you have to return a matching value in a `return` statement inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double average(double monTemp, double tuesTemp, double wedTemp, double thursTemp, double satTemp, double sunTemp, double friTemp)
```

Return type is double. So you need return .
Its better to make the method as void.

```
public static void average(double monTemp, double tuesTemp, double wedTemp, double thursTemp, double satTemp, double sunTemp, double friTemp)
```

Comment: You should also answer his other question

Comment: If he return void and don't pass double average in entry. There are not average.

Comment: @Viresh Mathad > Thank you. I've changed that, but it's still underlining red when I call the methods in my switch ?

Comment: Methods have arguments but you aren't mentioning them.

Comment: Really?  A `void` method to calculate an average?  How is that going to work?

Comment: @Viresh Mathad > I have mentioned them below in my switch now but it still underlines red, saying 'identifier expected' I have done this >> case 2:

            day(double monTemp, double tuesTemp, double wedTemp,double thursTemp, double friTemp, double satTemp, double sunTemp);
            menu();
            break;

Comment: @SarahJones When you call a method, you don't need to specify the type of each argument.  In other words, don't write `day(double monTemp, double tuesTemp ...`, just `day(monTemp, tuesTemp ...` - the compiler already knows that these values are `double`.

Comment: Well, i have edited the code and re posted it.
Check it.

Answer (score 0):

There were some errors, i have rectified.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temp
{
 static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
 static int choice;
 static double average, finalAverage;
 static double monTemp,tuesTemp,wedTemp,thursTemp,friTemp,satTemp,sunTemp;




 public static void temp()
 {

  System.out.println("You have chosen option 1");
  System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Monday in degrees celsius");
  monTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();


  System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Tuesday in degrees celsius");
  tuesTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();


  System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Wednesday in degrees celsius");
  wedTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Thursday in degrees celsius");
  thursTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Friday in degrees celsius");
  friTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Saturday in degrees celsius");
  satTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Sunday in degrees celsius");
  sunTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

 }//Temp

 public static void day()
 {

  System.out.println("You have chosen to see the temperature for a specified day");
  System.out.println("Please choose a day below");
  System.out.println(" 1. Monday");
  System.out.println(" 2. Tuesday");
  System.out.println(" 3. Wednesday");
  System.out.println(" 4. Thursday");
  System.out.println(" 5. Friday");
  System.out.println(" 6. Saturday");
  System.out.println(" 7. Sunday ");
  choice = keyboard.nextInt();

  if (choice==1)

  {
     System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Monday");
     System.out.println(" The temperature for Monday is " +monTemp + "°C");
  }//if

  else if  ( choice== 2)
  {
     System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Tuesday");
     System.out.println(" The temperature for Tuesday " + tuesTemp+ "°C");

  }//if
  else if ( choice== 3)
  {
     System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Wednesday");
     System.out.println(" The temperature for Wednesday is " +wedTemp + "°C");
  }//elseif
  else if ( choice== 4)
  {
     System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Thursday");
     System.out.println(" The temperature for Thursday is " +thursTemp + "°C");
  }//elseif
  else if ( choice== 5)
  {
     System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Friday");
     System.out.println(" The temperature for Friday is " +friTemp + "°C");
  }//elseif
  else if ( choice== 6)
  {
     System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Saturday");
     System.out.println(" The temperature for Saturday is " +satTemp + "°C");
  }//if
  else if (choice==7)
  {
     System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Sunday");
     System.out.println(" The temperature for Sunday is " +sunTemp + "°C");
  }//elseif
  else
  {
     System.out.println("Oops something went wrong, please try again");
     day();
  }//else



 }//day

 public static void average()
 {
  average=monTemp+tuesTemp+wedTemp+thursTemp+friTemp+satTemp+sunTemp;
  finalAverage=(average/7);

  System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the average temperature for the week");
  System.out.println(" The temperature for the week is " +finalAverage + "°C");

  }//Average

 public static void menu()
 {

  System.out.println("Welcome the temperature program. Please select an option for the menu below b entering the number");
  System.out.println("1)Enter temperatures for each day of the week");
  System.out.println("2)Display average temperature for specified choice");
  System.out.println("3)Display average temperature for the week");
  System.out.println("4)Exit");
  choice = keyboard.nextInt();

  switch (choice)
  {
     case 1:

        temp();
        menu();
        break;


     case 2:

       day();
        menu();
        break;

     case 3:

        average();
        menu();
        break;


     case 4:

        System.exit(0);



     default:
        System.out.println("Oops, something went wrong, please try again!");
        menu();
    }//switch
 }//menu

 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  menu();

  }//main
 }//class
```

Comment: A wall of code without any explanation of what you've actually fixed isn't much help to people who encounter this question in future; and it's only useful to Sarah if all she's interested in is cutting and pasting to pass her assignment.  I don't see the usefulness of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

You must return a double in you method average : "public static **double**"

```
public static double average(double monTemp, double tuesTemp, double wedTemp, double thursTemp, double satTemp, double sunTemp, double friTemp) {
      double average=monTemp+tuesTemp+wedTemp+thursTemp+friTemp+satTemp+sunTemp;
      finalAverage=(average/7);

      System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the average temperature for the week");
      System.out.println(" The temperature for the week is " +finalAverage + "°C");

      return average;
}
```

Comment: If you use a variable called `average` to store something that's not the average at all, you're likely to return the wrong value by mistake.

Comment: Don't you mean finalAverage instead?

Answer (score -1):

One way to fix your problems:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temp {
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
static int choice;
static double average, finalAverage;

static double monTemp, tuesTemp, wedTemp, thursTemp, friTemp, satTemp, sunTemp;

public static void temp() {

    System.out.println("You have chosen option 1");
    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Monday in degrees celsius");
    monTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Tuesday in degrees celsius");
    tuesTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Wednesday in degrees celsius");
    wedTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Thursday in degrees celsius");
    thursTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Friday in degrees celsius");
    friTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Saturday in degrees celsius");
    satTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Sunday in degrees celsius");
    sunTemp = keyboard.nextDouble();

}// Temp

public static void day() {

    System.out.println("You have chosen to see the temperature for a specified day");
    System.out.println("Please choose a day below");
    System.out.println(" 1. Monday");
    System.out.println(" 2. Tuesday");
    System.out.println(" 3. Wednesday");
    System.out.println(" 4. Thursday");
    System.out.println(" 5. Friday");
    System.out.println(" 6. Saturday");
    System.out.println(" 7. Sunday ");
    choice = keyboard.nextInt();

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Monday");
        System.out.println(" The temperature for Monday is " + monTemp + "°C");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Tuesday");
        System.out.println(" The temperature for Tuesday " + tuesTemp + "°C");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Wednesday");
        System.out.println(" The temperature for Wednesday is " + wedTemp + "°C");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Thursday");
        System.out.println(" The temperature for Thursday is " + thursTemp + "°C");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Friday");
        System.out.println(" The temperature for Friday is " + friTemp + "°C");
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Saturday");
        System.out.println(" The temperature for Saturday is " + satTemp + "°C");
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the temperature for Sunday");
        System.out.println(" The temperature for Sunday is " + sunTemp + "°C");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Oops something went wrong, please try again");
        break;

    }

}// day

public static void average() {
    average = monTemp + tuesTemp + wedTemp + thursTemp + friTemp + satTemp + sunTemp;
    finalAverage = (average / 7);

    System.out.println(" You have chosen to see the average temperature for the week");
    System.out.println(" The temperature for the week is " + finalAverage + "°C");

}// Average

public static void menu() {

    System.out.println("Welcome the temperature program. Please select an option for the menu below b entering the number");
    System.out.println("1)Enter temperatures for each day of the week");
    System.out.println("2)Display average temperature for specified choice");
    System.out.println("3)Display average temperature for the week");
    System.out.println("4)Exit");
    choice = keyboard.nextInt();

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        temp();
        menu();
        break;

    case 2:
        day();
        menu();
        break;

    case 3:
        average();
        menu();
        break;
    case 4:
        System.exit(0);
    default:
        System.out.println("Oops, something went wrong, please try again!");
        menu();
    }// switch
}// menu

public static void main(String[] args) {
    menu();
}// main
}// class
```

Comment: A wall of code without any explanation of what you've actually fixed isn't much help to people who encounter this question in future; and it's only useful to Sarah if all she's interested in is cutting and pasting to pass her assignment.  I don't see the usefulness of this answer.

Comment: I don't think anybody would ever use this question/answer to solve his own problem. It is very specific and the code is full of errors/anti-patterns. I posted my answer to at least help one person. On a side note, didn't you used to work at Dunder Mifflin ?

Comment: Down voted because no explanation

Comment: @JClassic please be my guest.